# InetAddress.getByName returns "akamaitechnologies.com for non-existent host

Tags: java, android, inetaddress

I have found that resolution of a hostname that does *NOT* exist always returns an address belonging to "akamaitechnologies.com" (e.g. 23.221.222.250). It *does* work correctly for hosts that *do* exist.

**Code:**

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName( "NON-EXISTING.com" );
```

The documentation for InetAddress or a Google search provide little help.  It is claimed that an UnknownHostException should occur but that does not happen for me.

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: Might be what the DNS server returns. What DNS server is being used? https://techwiser.com/check-your-dns-server/
Is the result the same if you change the DNS server to Cloudflare? https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/setting-up-1.1.1.1

Comment: @Max: Thanks for the tip. Network Info II reports DNS of 192.192.1.254 (my AT&T gateway. My gateway reports DNS of 68.94.156.11 (dns156r11.sbcglobal.net). I haven't figured out how to change it yet. Don't know where that came from, maybe AT&T default. What DNS would you recommend?

Comment: Cloudflare - 1.1.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an Android/Java defect. It turns out it was a DNS issue. Namely, my AT&T phone uses AT&T's default DNS server (sbcglobal.net). This P.O.S. server returns a valid IP address **even for non-existent domains**. After I changed to "dns.google" (8.8.8.8), everything worked as expected.

This DNS spoofing is a Bad Thing because many apps depened on a Unknown-Host-Exception to detect an incorrectly entered domain, e.g. in an email address.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a somewhat common technique of getting additional traffic/ads by your ISP. It also breaks quite some stuff (a surprising amount of tech depends on missing hosts actually not resolving). It's effectively [DNS Hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking).

Comment: @Joachim: I agree. And I'm a bit surprised that AT&T would be complicit in this DNS Hijacking scheme.

Comment: Really? They're not exactly know for consumer-friendly behaviour, are they? ;-)